# Compiling OpenCV creates cuda error - recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/opengl.cpp.o' failed

Tags: docker, opencv, cmake, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to compile openCV but it doesn't seem to work somehow.

Is this a problem with cuda?

I am running this in a docker-container (nvidia-docker)

Hardware is a Jetson Nano with newest JetPack - Version

What could that problem be?

```sh
[ 32%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/opengl.cpp.o
In file included from /opencv/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp:48:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_gl_interop.h:63:2: error: #error Please include the appropriate gl headers before including cuda_gl_interop.h
 #error Please include the appropriate gl headers before including cuda_gl_interop.h
  ^~~~~
[ 32%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/out.cpp.o
In file included from /opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:73:0,
                 from /opencv/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:56,
                 from /opencv/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp:43:
/opencv/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp: In function ‘void cv::cuda::setGlDevice(int)’:
/opencv/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp:118:47: warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaGLSetGLDevice(int)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         cudaSafeCall( cudaGLSetGLDevice(device) );
                                               ^
/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cuda/common.hpp:74:58: note: in definition of macro ‘cudaSafeCall’
     #define cudaSafeCall(expr)  cv::cuda::checkCudaError(expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, CV_Func)
                                                          ^~~~
In file included from /opencv/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp:48:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_gl_interop.h:305:57: note: declared here
 extern __CUDA_DEPRECATED __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaGLSetGLDevice(int device);
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:1368: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/opengl.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/opengl.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2763: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Some info:

```
 General configuration for OpenCV 4.1.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2020-01-06T00:19:08Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.9.140-tegra aarch64
--     CMake:                       3.10.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    NEON FP16
--       required:                  NEON
--       disabled:                  VFPV3
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          m pthread /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so cudart_static -lpthread dl rt /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so nppc nppial nppicc nppicom nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cufft -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
--     3rdparty dependencies:
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj hdf java js matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
--     Applications:                apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
--
--   GUI:
--     QT:                          YES (ver 5.9.5)
--       QT OpenGL support:         YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.9.5)
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so)
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
--
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2017.0 interface 9107)
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.4)
--     Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
--
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.0, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             53
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
--
--   cuDNN:                         NO
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.6 (ver 3.6.9)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.9)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.18.0)
--     install path:                lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6
--
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3.6
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd really appreciate some help, i couldn't find anything on the web sadly

Big thanks!

Comment: Doesnt JetPack already include OpenCV?

Comment: @Sharan it does but it's not working with CUDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the nvidia-libraries.

So i took the lib-files from the JetPack download-folder

and used them

-worked!